# How to communicate between gin and Python

Tags: python, go, go-gin

Here is my Go gin code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type Data struct {
    Test string `json:"test"`
}

func getData(c *gin.Context) {
    var data Data
    err := c.BindJSON(&data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(data)
    c.JSON(200, gin.H{
        "message": "pong",
    })
}

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.POST("/test", getData)
    r.Run() // listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080
}
```

and my python code:

```
import requests
r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/test",json={"test":"ok"})
print(r)
```

But when I execute my Python script I have a 403 error:

```
<Response [403]>
```

The panic (err) display nothing.

Any idea why I get this error?

Comment: May be you use a nginx or some proxy with authentication/authorization? Your code on python and Go are correct. `print(os.environ("HTTP_PROXY"))`

Comment: I checked both your python and go code and there was no problem. check your firewall and network proxy.Also try using postman to check your api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `go` and `python` code is valid. I check in my side don't have any error occur. 
Try setup `GET` router and check it with browser.

```
r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.String(http.StatusOK, "OK")
})
```

Comment: it was a proxy problem.